# Как в Php/Laravel создавать функции для отдельных записей?

Tags: php, laravel

Не знал как конкретнее назвать топик, так что извеняйте.

На данный момент я разрабатываю систему, где можно самому создать свой чатбот себе на сайт.

Появилась потребность в добавлении дополнительного функционала для одного уже существующего чатбота, а если быть точным - надо добавить специальные фильтры для пользовательского ввода. К примеру, для одного чатбота надо фильтр на "Номер кредитной карты в Латвии" - чтобы когда пользователь вводил неверный номер карточки, ему выводилась ошибка. Остальным чатботам такой функционал **не нужен**".

На данный момент фильтры работают так: пользователь ввел текст, а он обрабатывается нужным REGEX (регулярным выражением) из базы данных. Но ведь будут случаи, когда REGEX-ом не обработаешь некоторые данные.

Вопрос, как с точки зрения чистого кода это лучше сделать? Кроме банального `if chatbot_id == x { filterLatvianCreditCard(); }` в голову ничего не приходит. Желательно чтобы процесс отсоеденения этого "дополнения" был простым.

Код пишу на Laravel.

Comment: @Akina ну я ее использую как БД. Возможно решение связано с ним :/

Comment: ну как же вы достали... Щас из-за вас web-разработчики не нужны будут, из-за wix и всей этой херне

Comment: @Lofectr. к сожалению надо адаптироваться, если не мы - то нас :((

Comment: лучше уж нас, весь интернет винить будет в том числе и тебя

Answer (score 3):

Это вопрос архитектуры и масштабирования. Обычно подобные проблемы решаются применением [паттернов проектирования](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/php).

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, то самое простое решение на мой взгляд выглядит так:

Создаем модель бота Bot и модель фильтра BotFilter

Один бот может поддерживать несколько фильтров. В базе храним название фильтра, каждому фильтру соответствует своя реализация.

---

Все фильтры реализуют один интерфейс.

```
interface Filter {
    public function run(array $data);
}

class CreditCardFilter implements Filter {

    public function run(array $data)
    {
        if($this->isValid($data))
            ....
    }
}
```

---

Так же понадобиться фабрика для получения объекта фильтра по названию из бд.

```
class FilterFactory {
    public static function getInstance(BotFilterModel $model): Filter {
        if($model->getName()==='credit_card_filter')
            return new CreditCardFilter();
        elseif ($model->getName()==='name_filter')
            return new NameFilter();
        else
            return new DefaultFilter();
    }
}
```

---

Таким образом, код обработки будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$bot = Bot::query()->find(100); //получаем модель бота из бд
$botFilters = $bot->getFilters(); //по связи получаем список фильтров

foreach ($botFilters as $botFilter) {
    FilterFactory::getInstance($botFilter)->run($data);
}
```

То есть применяем все фильтры, которые указаны в настройках бота.

---

Таким образом любому боту можно добавлять/убирать фильтры. Все фильтры имеют свою реализацию и легко дополняются/расширяются.

Так же рекомендую обратить внимание на паттерн [цепочка обязанностей](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility) и реализацию [pipeline в laravel.](https://habr.com/ru/post/429214/)